# JTable: align the component from right to left

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to align the whole `JTable` (not only the values of cells) from the right to the left.

I did the following things:

```
table.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
table.getTableHeader().setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

The content of the table has been successfully oriented but the problem is in the header
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT) on the parent component. As mentioned in [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4514643)

Comment: I'm putting this `jTable` inside a `JScrollPane`, I set the orientation to `JScrollPane ` from right to left but still same problem.